# Entity Framework : cant assign found object to my property

Tags: entity-framework

Im Creating a Expediente , and I can get all the data without problem , except for Funcionario.
When I try to assign it as

```
ex.Funcionario = funcionario as Funcionario;
```

gets me a null
but if I try to just assign it like

```
ex.Funcionario= db.Funcionario.Where(F => F.Email == vm.idFuncionario).Include(F => F.Grupo);
```

I get an "cant convert implicit type." error.
Any Idea about how can I assign that Funcionario to the property on Expediente without loosing its data?

```
public ActionResult Create(ExpedienteCrearViewModel vm)
        {

            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                Expediente ex = new Expediente();
                
                var funcionario = db.Funcionario.Where(F => F.Email == vm.idFuncionario).Include(F => F.Grupo);
                ex.Funcionario = funcionario as Funcionario;
            
                ex.Tramite = db.Tramite.Find(vm.idTramite);

                ex.Solicitante = (Solicitante)Session["solicitante"];
                ex.abierto = true;
                ex.FechaCreacion = DateTime.Now;
                db.Expediente.Add(ex);
                db.SaveChanges();
                vm.Trsmites = new SelectList(db.Tramite.ToList(), "Codigo", "Titulo");
                vm.Funcionarios = new SelectList(db.Funcionario.ToList(), "Email", "Nombre");
            }

            return View(vm);
        }
```

here is the Expediente Class

```
public class Expediente
    {
        //Para que sea key y no genere identity la BD 
        [Key]
        public int Codigo { get; set; }
   
        [Required]
        public Tramite Tramite { get; set; }

        //no le pongo requiered para que no de error al crearlo sin esto
        public DateTime FechaCreacion { get; set; }

        //por defecto hay que ponerlo en true
        public Boolean abierto { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public Funcionario Funcionario { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public Solicitante Solicitante { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<EtapaCumplida> etapasCumplidas { get; set; }

    }
```

Comment: What is the type of `Funcionario` property? Just show us the `Expediente` class

Comment: I just add the Expediente class code. Funcionario is an object of the type Funcionario

Comment: try Adding a .FirstOrDefault to the end of the line. The Where statement returns an IQueryable of Functionario, while the property in your entity is a single functionario.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following variable `funcionario` defined like below:

```
var funcionario = db.Funcionario.Where(F => F.Email == vm.idFuncionario).Include(F => F.Grupo);
```

return an `IQueryable<Funcionario>` which can't converted implcitly or explictly like you do in the line below:

```
ex.Funcionario = funcionario as Funcionario;
```

You should first execute your query so it returns one instance of `Funcionario` so just use this:

```
var funcionario = db.Funcionario
                    .Where(F => F.Email == vm.idFuncionario).Include(F => F.Grupo)
                    .SingleOrDefault();
ex.Funcionario = funcionario;
```

`SingleOrDefault()` execute the query and returns one instance of `Funcionario`.
My code pretends that a "functionario" is unique per email. If you think there must be more "functionario" for same email so just replace `SingleOrDefault()` with `FirstOrDefault()`.

Side Note: you can pass the condition directly to the `SingleOrDefault()` method like below:

```
var funcionario = db.Funcionario
                    .Include(F => F.Grupo)
                    .SingleOrDefault(F => F.Email == vm.idFuncionario);
ex.Funcionario = funcionario;
```

Comment: I tryed this, and It worked just fine. Now I can get the Funcionario.

Comment: The only problem is that now I get an "Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_dbo.Solicitante'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.Solicitante'. The duplicate key value is (15301123).
The statement has been terminated." Error when the db.SaveChanges(); line is executed. on the Create

Comment: You should replace this line `ex.Solicitante = (Solicitante)Session["solicitante"];` with these 3 lines `var solicitante = (Solicitante)Session["solicitante"]; db.Solicitante.Attach(solicitante); ex.Solicitante = solicitante`